# Concurrent MySQL transactions causing a lock-up using MySQL Connector (.NET)

Tags: mysql, .net, vb.net

This has me stumped and I'm getting a bit frustrated. I'm trying to implement a system where there is a timer that periodically queries a MySQL table to get updates. When one of these routine queries is being performed, the user may (in another window) attempt to execute an unrelated SQL expression in the same database table. For some reason when I try read records that are currently locked in a transaction, the entire thread locks up and the MySQL connection times out. What I expected was for the second connection to wait until the first connection (transaction) was complete and then it would fire.

I did a test with two instances of the program running and it works fine, the second connection waits for the first connection to complete (in the alternate exe). But if I try to run two async functions with this code it locks. So I'm thinking this is a thread issue? I boiled down the code to the relevant parts that causes the problem.

```
Dim conn As New MySqlConnection(MySqlConnectionString)

Try
    conn.Open()
    Dim trans As MySqlTransaction = conn.BeginTransaction
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("Set time_zone='-4:00'; Select * From Products For Update;", conn, trans)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Await Task.Delay(10000)
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("error " + ex.Message)
End Try

conn.Close()
```

(I removed the `ExecuteReader` for simplicity).
I hope the solution is something simple I'm overlooking.

Note: the task.delay is used to give me enough time to click the second button to start the second connection.

Edit: ASYNC methods (eg. OpenAsync) don't make any difference.

Comment: Entirely expected. Transactions should be as short as possible, to avoid locking things up for too long. Generally you should avoid a client-side transaction anyway, because of the extra round-trip time. And you shouldn't block with a `MessageBox` or anything while the connection is open. Side point: you should have `Using` blocks on all the SQL objects.

Comment: The problem is it never unlocks. Even if it's a very short delay it still locks things up permanently.  ---- also I moved the error reporting outside the connection code 

Comment: Well you are not committing or rolling back the transaction, nor are you disposing it with `Using`. That is how it is supposed to work, not sure what else you expected. Transactions are designed to hold onto locks until you tell them to let go, which you are not doing. [You need to read up](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/local-transactions#example) on how to use transactions. The reason you don't see this when things are executed one after another is probably because eventually the connection gets automatically closed and the transaction rolled back

Comment: It sounds like you're hitting the MySql command timeout. You can adjust this setting in your query string. Also, MySql is not like MsSql in the sense that timeouts are *normal*, and your application code needs to handle them.